# Topic related tag repository

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a custom, user maintaned repository that organize tags by topic?

For example I would like to browse (or find unaswered questions for) the general topic "software engineering" so it should include tags like:

software-engineering, SOLID, continuous-integration, OOP, dependency-inversion, IoC, class-desgin, SCRUM, extreme-programming ...

I then would like to predefine a query for me personally that give me all unaswered questions in a given general topic. Without having to specify all those specifc tags.

Comment: Have you tried out tag sets? http://stackexchange.com/tagsets

Comment: That doesn't seem to quite fit my needs: 1. I can't search for a an exisiting tagset of a certain topic and then use it. 2. I have to actually create the tagset myself, wich means I have to know all exisiting tags that belong to the topic I am looking for. I think it would be way better if there would be a community driven repository where all users can add and remove tags for a given topic.